# How would one achieve conditional compilation with Rust projects that have doctests?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I've used conditional compilation to change the type signature of a function, and now the same doctest can't be run for both "feature" modes, so I need a way to opt-out of the doctests.

I've tried merging `#[cfg_attr(feature = "rss_loose", ignore)]` used in normal tests and `///rust,ignore` to make `///rust,cfg_attr(feature = "rss_loose", ignore)` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does `#[cfg_attr]` works inside the doctest? You could then hide it with [`#`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/documentation.html#documentation-as-tests).

Answer (score 8):

Just write two different sets of documentation and tests and it will all work as-is:

````
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(42, dt::foo());
/// ```
#[cfg(not(feature = "alternate"))]
pub fn foo() -> u8 { 42 }

/// ```
/// assert_eq!(true, dt::foo());
/// ```
#[cfg(feature = "alternate")]
pub fn foo() -> bool { true }
````

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling dt v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/dt)
     Running target/debug/dt-c3e297f8592542b5

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

   Doc-tests dt

running 1 test
test foo_0 ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

```
$ cargo test --features=alternate
   Compiling dt v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/dt)
     Running target/debug/dt-c3e297f8592542b5

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

   Doc-tests dt

running 1 test
test foo_0 ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Comment: Only problem with this was that I was trying to do this for a module documentation, so there were no two different functions to write docs for. But your method is a much better one.

Answer (score 5):

At least as of Rust 1.55 edition 2018, a documentation test can be ignored with an annotation like the following:

````
/// ```ignore
/// do_something();
/// ```
````

Moreover, each documentation comment line is actually translated into an individual attribute, like so:

````
#[doc = " ```ignore"]
#[doc = " do_something();"]
#[doc = " ```"]
````

This means that the line saying ```` ```ignore ```` can be conditionally replaced, using [the `cfg_attr` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute), with one just saying ```` ``` ````, to activate the test:

````
#[cfg_attr(feature = "extra-doctests", doc = "```")]
#[cfg_attr(not(feature = "extra-doctests"), doc = "```ignore")]
/// do_something();
/// ```
````

When tests are run with the `extra-doctests` feature enabled, this doc-test will run normally; when this feature is disabled, it will appear as "ignored" in the log.