# How can I conditionally execute a module-level doctest based on a feature flag?

Tags: rust, automated-tests, documentation, conditional-compilation

I am writing documentation for a module that has some options controlled by a Cargo feature flag. I'd like to always show this documentation so that consumers of the crate know that it's available, but I need to only run the example when the feature is enabled.

#### lib.rs

````
//! This crate has common utility functions
//!
//! ```
//! assert_eq!(2, featureful::add_one(1));
//! ```
//!
//! You may also want to use the feature flag `solve_halting_problem`:
//!
//! ```
//! assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
//! ```

pub fn add_one(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a + 1
}

#[cfg(feature = "solve_halting_problem")]
pub fn is_p_equal_to_np() -> bool {
    true
}
````

#### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "featureful"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]

[features]
solve_halting_problem = []

[dependencies]
```

---

Running with the feature enabled runs both doctests as expected:

```
$ cargo test --features=solve_halting_problem
   Doc-tests featureful

running 2 tests
test src/lib.rs -  (line 7) ... ok
test src/lib.rs -  (line 3) ... ok

test result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Running without the feature has an error:

```
$ cargo test
   Doc-tests featureful

running 2 tests
test src/lib.rs -  (line 7) ... FAILED
test src/lib.rs -  (line 3) ... ok

failures:

---- src/lib.rs -  (line 7) stdout ----
    error[E0425]: cannot find function `is_p_equal_to_np` in module `featureful`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:21
  |
4 | assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `featureful`
```

Both the ```` ```ignore ```` and ```` ```no_run ````  modifiers apply  when the feature is enabled or not, so they don't seem to be useful.

---

[How would one achieve conditional compilation with Rust projects that have doctests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38292741/155423) is close, but the answer focuses on *functions* that change with conditional compilation, not on documentation of *modules*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I only see one solution: put the `#[cfg]` inside the test:

````
//! ```
//! #[cfg(feature = "solve_halting_problem")]
//! assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
//! ```
````

This will count as a test but it will be empty when the feature is not enabled. You can pair this with the ability to [hide portions of the example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#hiding-portions-of-the-example) and the fact that you can put the `#[cfg]` attribute on entire blocks as well:

````
//! ```
//! # #[cfg(feature = "solve_halting_problem")] {
//! assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
//! // Better double check
//! assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
//! # }
//! ```
````

---

As a note, maybe you could use [`#![feature(doc_cfg)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/unstable-features.html#documenting-platform-feature-specific-information) like this:

````
/// This function is super useful
///
/// ```
/// assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
/// ```
#[cfg(any(feature = "solve_halting_problem", feature = "dox"))]
#[doc(cfg(feature = "solve_halting_problem"))]
pub fn is_p_equal_to_np() -> bool {
    true
}
````

This will not run the test when the feature is disabled but this will generate the doc with `cargo doc --features dox`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, too, and I think is much cleaner:

````rust
//! This crate has common utility functions
//!
//! ```
//! assert_eq!(2, featureful::add_one(1));
//! ```
//!
#![cfg_attr(
    not(feature = "solve_halting_problem"),
    doc = "You may also want to use the feature flag `solve_halting_problem`:"
)]
#![cfg_attr(
    feature = "solve_halting_problem",
    doc = "This example works because the `solve_halting_problem` feature flag is enabled:"
)]
//!
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "solve_halting_problem"), doc = "```ignore")]
#![cfg_attr(feature = "solve_halting_problem", doc = "```")]
//! assert!(featureful::is_p_equal_to_np());
//! ```
````